# Find min/max of complex 2D array

Tags: php, arrays

PHP is not usually my language so please bear with me.

I have a (in my opinion) poorly designed 2D array of product categories and I would like to get the min/max of the two ratings per sub-category. Sadly, I cannot change the layout of the array:

```
[[Category, SubCategory, OverallRating, ExtraRating]]
```

For example, some sample data is like this:

```
[["Fridges",         "Samsung", 5, 6],
 ["Fridges",         "Samsung", 2, 1],
 ["Fridges",         "Samsung", 3, 4],
 ["Fridges",         "LG",      7, 5],
 ["Washing Machine", "Letto",   5, 6],
 ["Washing Machine", "Samsung", 5, 6],
 ["Fridges",         "Samsung", 4, 4]]
```

The output of this should give me data such that:

```
Fridges, Samsung: 2/5, 1/6
Fridges, LG: 7/7, 5/5 (or just 7, 5)
Washing Machine, Letto: 5, 6 (see above)
Washing Machine, Samsung: 5, 6 (see above)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php

$your_array = array(array("Fridges", "Samsung", 5, 6), array("Fridges", "Samsung", 2, 1), array("Fridges", "Samsung", 3, 4), array("Fridges", "LG", 7, 5), array("Washing Machine", "Letto", 5, 6), array("Washing Machine", "Samsung", 5, 6), array("Fridges", "Samsung", 4, 4));

$arr_temp = array();
foreach($your_array as $key=>$arr)
{
     $category = $arr[0];
     $sub_category = $arr[1];
     $overall_rating = $arr[2];
     $extra_rating = $arr[3];

     if(isset($arr_temp[$category][$sub_category]['overall']))
     {
        $overall_min =  $arr_temp[$category][$sub_category]['overall']['min'];
        $overall_max =  $arr_temp[$category][$sub_category]['overall']['max'];

        if($overall_rating<$overall_min)
        {
            $arr_temp[$category][$sub_category]['overall']['min'] = $overall_rating;
        }
        if($overall_rating>$overall_max)
        {
            $arr_temp[$category][$sub_category]['overall']['max'] = $overall_rating;
        }

     }
     else
     {
        $arr_temp[$category][$sub_category]['overall']['min'] = $overall_rating;
        $arr_temp[$category][$sub_category]['overall']['max'] = $overall_rating;
     }


     if(isset($arr_temp[$category][$sub_category]['extra']))
     {
        $extra_min =  $arr_temp[$category][$sub_category]['extra']['min'];
        $extra_max =  $arr_temp[$category][$sub_category]['extra']['max'];

        if($extra_rating<$extra_min)
        {
            $arr_temp[$category][$sub_category]['extra']['min'] = $extra_rating;
        }
        if($extra_rating>$extra_max)
        {
            $arr_temp[$category][$sub_category]['extra']['max'] = $extra_rating;
        }

     }
     else
     {
        $arr_temp[$category][$sub_category]['extra']['min'] = $extra_rating;
        $arr_temp[$category][$sub_category]['extra']['max'] = $extra_rating;
     }


}

foreach($arr_temp as $category=>$arr1)
{
    foreach($arr1 as $sub_category=>$arr2)
    {
        echo $category.",".$sub_category.":".$arr2['overall']['min']."/".$arr2['overall']['max'].",".$arr2['extra']['min']."/".$arr2['extra']['max'];
        echo "\n";
    }
}
?>
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
Fridges,Samsung:2/5,1/6
Fridges,LG:7/7,5/5
Washing Machine,Letto:5/5,6/6
Washing Machine,Samsung:5/5,6/6
```

**[DEMO](https://eval.in/180327)**

Answer (score 0):

How about this code?

**Source:**

```
<?php
    function calculate($input)
    {
        $res = array();
        foreach ($input as $data) {
            $key = $data[0].", ".$data[1];
            $overall = $data[2];
            $extra = $data[3];
            if (isset($res[$key])) {    // existing one
                if ($res[$key]["overall_min"] > $overall) {
                    $res[$key]["overall_min"] = $overall;
                }
                if ($res[$key]["overall_max"] < $overall) {
                    $res[$key]["overall_max"] = $overall;
                }
                if ($res[$key]["extra_min"] > $extra) {
                    $res[$key]["extra_min"] = $extra;
                }
                if ($res[$key]["extra_max"] < $extra) {
                    $res[$key]["extra_max"] = $extra;
                }
            }
            else {  // new one
                $res[$key] = array(
                    "key" => $key,
                    "overall_min" => $overall,
                    "overall_max" => $overall,
                    "extra_min" => $extra,
                    "extra_max" => $extra
                );
            }
        }
        return $res;
    }

    // set input
    $input = 
        [["Fridges",         "Samsung", 5, 6],
         ["Fridges",         "Samsung", 2, 1],
         ["Fridges",         "Samsung", 3, 4],
         ["Fridges",         "LG",      7, 5],
         ["Washing Machine", "Letto",   5, 6],
         ["Washing Machine", "Samsung", 5, 6],
         ["Fridges",         "Samsung", 4, 4]];

    // calculate
    $res = calculate($input);

    // print
    foreach ($res as $data) {
        echo sprintf(
            "%s: %d/%d, %d/%d<br />\n", 
            $data["key"], $data["overall_min"], $data["overall_max"], $data["extra_min"], $data["extra_max"]
        );
    }
?>
```

**Output:**

`Fridges, Samsung: 2/5, 1/6
Fridges, LG: 7/7, 5/5
Washing Machine, Letto: 5/5, 6/6
Washing Machine, Samsung: 5/5, 6/6`

[Demo page](http://codepad.viper-7.com/owCTTl)